# Проблемы с js после смены ориентации мобильного устройства

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

Нужно на определённой ширины устройствах скрывать элемент и показывать его по клику на ссылку. Ссылке добавить класс для оформления. По повторному клику обратный процесс. Написал код:

```
// Mobile
$(window).resize(function() {
    winSize();
});
var windowSize;
function winSize(){
    windowSize =  window.matchMedia("(max-width: 460px)").matches;
    if (windowSize) {
        $(".element").hide();
        $(".link").on("click",function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("open");
            $(".element").toggle(300);
        })
    } else {
        $(".link").removeClass("open");
        $(".element").show();
    }
}
winSize();
```

При смене ориентации, если ширина становится больше заданной, то элемент нужно отобразить, убрать класс у ссылки. При повторной смене ориентации элемент скрывается, но при клике на ссылку он отображается и снова скрывается.
В чём может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте unbind() для снятия обработчика click:

```
if (windowSize) {
    $(".element").hide();
        $(".link").on("click",function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("open");
        $(".element").toggle(300);
    })
} else {
    $(".link").unbind().removeClass("open");
    $(".element").show();
}
```